# JOIN and sprintf rather than two queries and echo

Tags: php, mysql

It works fine, however it's a little messy. I understand it would be better for performance to use JOIN and have been advised before to use `sprintf`. However, it's pretty confusing and I cannot understand the PHP tutorials on it.

```
<?php
$exerciseID = get_the_ID();
$blogUrl = get_site_url();

global $wpdb;

$getImageIdQuery = "
SELECT image_map
FROM wp_posts
WHERE ID = '".$exerciseID."'";

$imageID = $wpdb->get_results($getImageIdQuery);

foreach($imageID as $row2) {
 }

$mappedImage = $row2->image_map;

$query = "
SELECT id 
FROM imagemap
WHERE exercise = '".$mappedImage."'";

$result = $wpdb->get_results($query); 

foreach($result as $row) {
 }
echo '<div class="thumbnail-title-block">';
echo '<p>' .the_title(). '</p>';
echo '</div>';
echo "<img src=".$blogUrl. "/image/medium/".$row->id. ".jpg />";

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Escaping Variable Part of Query**

Check out [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) and [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation#Database) post about correctly using the wordpress database class to avoid SQL injection. Even if the variable data is not directly user supplied, I would always use prepared statements or at least escape data as defense in depth, and to prevent [second order SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Second_Order_SQL_Injection).

Your code should look something like this:

```
$getImageIdQuery = "
SELECT image_map
FROM wp_posts
WHERE ID = %d";

$sql = $wpdb->prepare( $getImageIdQuery, $exerciseID );
$imageID = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

Same goes for the other query (the added benefit is that this way, you don't need `sprintf` because the SQL code and the PHP code are already separated).

**Escaping Variable Part of Output**

I would also [sanitize all variable data when echoing it to the user](http://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data#Escaping:_Securing_Output). Right now, anybody who can create posts can include arbitrary javascript via `the_title`. This might actually be ok, but still, to be save I would write it like this:

```
echo '<div class="thumbnail-title-block">';
echo '<p>' . esc_html(the_title()) . '</p>';
echo '</div>';
echo "<img src=". esc_url($blogUrl . "/image/medium/".$row->id. ".jpg") . "/>";
```

**Foreach**

You have two `foreach` statements which do not do anything. but their side-effect is that your are always only working on the last entry retrieved by the query.

Instead of returning all matching entries, you should only retrieve this one entry and remove your `foreach` loops (you can use `get_row` (if needed in combination with `limit` and `order by`)).

**Misc**

- I would use more spaces to make the code more readable (for example around `.`). See also the [wordpress style guide](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/php/#space-usage).
- use single and double quotes consistently (for example `"<img src="` vs `'</div>'`; both should use single quotes)

**sprintf**

I don't really like using `sprintf`, but if you want to, it would look like this:

```
echo '<div class="thumbnail-title-block">';
echo sprintf('<p>%s</p>', esc_html(the_title()));
echo '</div>';
echo sprintf("<img src=%s/>", esc_url($blogUrl . "/image/medium/".$row->id. ".jpg"));
```

`%s` is a placeholder for any string (you would use `%d` for numbers), and it will be replaced by the rest of the arguments for `sprintf`.

The advantage is that you do not have PHP variables/function calls inside your HTML/SQL/etc.

**join**

You can read about join [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) and a bit more in-depth [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/).

Your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT imagemap.id FROM imagemap JOIN wp_posts ON imagemap.exercise = wp_posts.image_map WHERE wp_posts.ID = $exerciseID
```

What it basically does is combine the two tables (based on the `ON` clause).

For example, if the tables looked like this:

```
imagemap:
id exercise
1  1
2  2
3  2
4  3

wp_posts:
pid image_map
6   1
7   1
8   2
```

the combined table would look like this:

```
id exercise pid image_map
1  1        6   1
1  1        7   1 
2  2        8   2
3  2        8   2
```

and then the where clause is applied (I called `wp_posts.ID` `pid` for the example).

Comment: Would join be a lot faster than two queries?

Comment: @Taylorsuk yes, I would assume so; this code is probably already quite fast, but for more complex queries it should definitely make a noticeable difference. And It also makes your code easier to read.